# Migrate Android app between companies (as into Applet Store)

Tags: android, google-play

maybe is a silly question, but a try.
I need to acquire an App from another company. This app is already deployed on Google and Apple stores and I'm wondering if I can to deploy a new release as update.
Into iTunes there is the migration functionality.
How can I do for Android? My first doubt is about the change of the package name.

I hope I was clear.

Thanks, Alessio.

Comment: "I hope I was clear.". No, this was not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Take over their Google account under which the original app was published. This will give you access to the Developer Console where you can upload updates and users will continue using the app as if nothing happened.
2. You can change the package name on the app and upload to your own Google account. Keep in mind this will not bring over any existing users and will show up as a completely different app. The current owner will need to delist the app from their account as well.

Comment: The first option is not possible, I'm sure they don't let me know him Google account pwd. :) Thanks for the answer.